# How to set field position on screen at any point on blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, user-interface

I am new to blackberry and i want to set one of my Field position to the left corner of screen & another field at right corner of screen at same level but i am unable to do it.how could it be possible?

I also don't want to give coordinate as a hard coded value but want to calculate using screen width & height cause i want to run same application on Torch I & Torch II model of blackberry.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `AbsoulteFieldManager` on screen and then you will have ability to set custom positions for your fields with `add(field, x, y)`.
Take a look on this [tutorial](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Display_button_halfway_down_screen_839917_11.jsp).